# play audio when the radio button is check or click

Tags: javascript, audio

```
<FORM>
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="select1" value="babai" />
        <label for="select1"><img src="Thesis pictures/girl.jpg" alt="Babai" style=width:150px; height=150x;/><br>Babai</label>
        </div>
    <div id="selection2">   
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="select2" value"lalaki"/>
        <label for="select2"><img src="Thesis pictures/boy.jpg" alt="lalaki" style=width:150px; height=150x; /><br>Lalaki</label>
    </div>
    <div id="selection3">
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="select3" value="aso"/>
        <label for="select3"><img src="Thesis pictures/dog.jpg" alt="aso" style=width:150px; height=150x;/><br>Aso</label>
    </div>
    </FORM>
```

This is the HTML of my page it has picture in it. I want that, if you click the picture or the radio it will immediately play the audio.

my javascript is in another file I tested it, it is connected.

```
function doFirst(){
    item1=document.getElementById('select1');
    item2=document.getElementById('select2');
    item3=document.getElementById('select3');
    var audio1 = new Audio('audio/babai.wav');
    var audio2 = new Audio('audio/lalaki.wav');
    var audio3 = new Audio('audio/aso.wav');

    item1.addEventListener('click',plays1,false);
    item2.addEventListener('click',plays2,false);
    item3.addEventListener('click',plays3,false);


}

function plays1(){
    audio1.play();
}

function plays2(){
    audio2.play();
}

function plays3(){
    audio3.play();
}


window.addEventListener('load',doFirst,false);
```

I use this code and nothing happens if I click any picture. can you guys help me with this and help me simply my code I will thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: use `change` events not `click` events

Comment: Still not working sir.. :(

Comment: DOH! `<label for="babai">` needs to be, eg, `<label for="select1">`

Comment: I changed it sir but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined your audio1-3 inside the initialisation function, they are limited in scope to that function so they are not available to the other functions at the time you make the click.

Move the audio1-3 outside of the scope of the function, either as global variables or into a wrapper of some sort.

To do this, move the following lines outside of the doFirst() function:

```js
var audio1 = new Audio('audio/babai.wav');
var audio2 = new Audio('audio/lalaki.wav');
var audio3 = new Audio('audio/aso.wav');
```

Comment: How to make it gobal variable sir?

Comment: Put the following outside of the doFirst() function: var audio1 = new Audio('audio/babai.wav');
    var audio2 = new Audio('audio/lalaki.wav');
    var audio3 = new Audio('audio/aso.wav');

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `window.addEventListener('load',doFirst,false);` you can use `window.onload(doFirst());`

You can add an `onclick` property to each radio. So for example:

```
<img src="Thesis pictures/dog.jpg" onclick="plays3()" alt="aso" style=width:150px; height=150x;/>
```

Also the 3 audio variables only exist within the `doFirst()` method. You need to declare them outside of the function and you can assign them within. You also haven't shown the declaration of the 3 item variables make sure they are declared properly with a `var` before them.

Comment: Thank you sir for the advice but that does not solve the problem still it does not play the audio when I click the radio with the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You added a click listner to radio. It only works when you click the radio button, not the image. But you can add a listener to the image label in a similar fashion.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hat2c461/) where you can mess with it.

```
var imgClickable = document.getElementById('clickable');
imgClickable.onclick = function(){
        alert('clicked Image');
    };
```

Comment: @MarkKleinFermin Did you actually try it in the fiddle ? I double checked it. It seems to be working from my angle. (Firefox 39.0)

Comment: Yes I tried it . but I applied it on my work it does not work. what seems to be the problem here? I double check the codes its the same.

Comment: @MarkKleinFermin Do you see alertboxes in the fiddle ?

Comment: I copied exactly your code sir but no alert box appeared. I think there is something wrong with my system.

Comment: yes sir @Alp  I see alert box of the fiddle in it using chrome.

Comment: Be careful with spelling. For example if you type onClick, it won't work. Or if you misspell tag id, it won't work either. I think you are missing something really small. Just be careful.

Comment: sir thank you for the advice but sir peter bailey solved my problem thankyou for your time sir.